# How to change animation view in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, curves

How can I change the animation view in Unity3D? I have only some "dot", but I want to view some curve! How do I change this?

What I have:[image]

And what I want:[image]

(image from the documentation of Unity3D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "dot" view is called a "Dopesheet"

From the [Unity animation curves docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/432/Documentation/Manual/UsingAnimCurves.html), "Click the Curves button at the bottom left of the window to change to the Curve view."

You can see the Curves button just beside the bottom scroll bar in this image from the [Unity Dopesheet docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/432/Documentation/Manual/UsingDopesheet.html):

[image]